# Sending a variable back to Express on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Let's say I have a list of 10 elements each with a unique id as their name and the user can add to the list whenever.

When I click an element, I want Express to get the id of the element I clicked. If it was just one element with a fixed id I could just use req.body.idname, but there can potentially be 100.

Is there a way to do this?

So far I have:

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {


  var x = $(this).attr('name');
  console.log(x);
});
```

which does get the correct name of the element but that's it.

What I'm trying to do is pass in the id as a parameter for a function like

```
exports.somePage = function(req, res){
    var id = //id from clicked element goes here
    //getElement finds the foo with the id
    databaseTable.getFoo(id, function (err, foo){
        if(err)
            console.log("error");
        else {
            res.render('page', { title: 'Page',
                foo : foo
        });
    }
});
```

};

Comment: Use AJAX or create routes like that `/getfoo/:id` i think. Or use query parameter (`/foo/?id=ID`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AJAX` to `POST` the data.

```
$("li").click(function()
{
    var ajaxData = {};
        ajaxData.name = $(this).attr('name');
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: ajaxData,
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/handleName'
    });
    request.success(function(data)
    {
        console.log("Success.");
        for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
        {
            // Optional to pass some data back.
        }
    });
    request.error(function(request, status, error)
    {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    });
});
```

Wherea your handleName looks something like this:

```
app.post("/handleName", function(request, response)
{
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1'); // Sometimes required.
    var name= request.body.name;
});
```

Maybe this isn't 100% copy/paste working for you but using AJAX and fetching the name in the request should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process. First on express you need the proper routing set:

**Server Side**

```
//app = express();
    app.get('/api/:paramID1/:paramID2',function(req, res){
    //your code req.params.paramID1 or req.params.paramID2
    });
```

On the **client side** you need a link that invokes the url or ajax like: `http://yourdomain/api/1/abc` where `1` and `abc` are `param1` and `param2` respectively.

So something as simple as: `<a href="/api/1/abc">Some Demo</a>` on click could send the information you need to the server. Or using a little bit more complex example with JQuery/Ajax:

```
$.get( "/api/1/abc", function( data ) {
  alert( "Load was performed. " + data );
});
```

Please note that when using rest there are different type of "methods" that can be invoke depending on your needs, such as POST, DELETE, UPDATE or the one just mentioned in the example GET.